Trouble connecting Windows 11 PC to Android 11 phone
Are there any special tricks to connect and Android phone to a PC?
Below's what I've tried so far, and without success.

On my Android phone (Android, version 11), the bluetooth is on and discoverable.

On my PC (Win. 11), I can see my phone's bluetooth name when going to "Bluetooth & devices" -> "Add device".

But when I click on my phone's name, it shows a message in red: "Try connecting your device again."

On my Android phone, I can detect my PC's name on bluetooth, but when I tried to connecting, the PC acknowledges a device, but doesn't go beyond that and ends in failure.

Additional note: On the same PC, multiple other bluetooth devices (i.e.: controllers, wireless headphones, etc.) have connected successfully. So I know my PC's bluetooth adapter works. My phone also connected to other bluetooth devices, so I know my phone's bluetooth adapter also works.



What's the purpose of connecting your phone and the PC?

To share my Android phone's data connection over Bluetooth to the PC via the "Bluetooth tethering" function.

So your PC has Bluetooth and no WiFi? Or you don't have a USB cable? BT is ridiculously slow compared to WiFi or able tethering.

That's alright, I'd like to get it working anyways. It looks like the answer so far is "no, in this situation there's no way to connect to bluetooth", which hopefully will not be the case.

Interestingly, on another Windows 10 PC, there were no problems connecting by bluetooth from the PC to the Android phone. Not sure how or why, perhaps it has something to do with either Windows 11 or the specific bluetooth hardware used?

Yes, regardless of the previous considerations it should be able to connect. It must be something specific to the PC.
